# Problems with Macros in MacVim

Tags: vim, macros, macvim

**Ignore this silly question**

In case anybody is wondering. It was the copy+paste that stopped it from working. Then you have to use a plugin like [Marvin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2154) to save it permanently. My bad.

---

I need to run a few commands on MacVim, mainly search and replace, on multiple files.

So I recorded a Macros while doing the first file,

```
q
```

to start recording the macros, then

```
c
```

to name the Macros,

then the following lines (copy and paste from a text file) are fed one by one

```
v/sequence One\|sequence two/d
%s/sequence three//g
%s/sequence four/,/g
%s/ /_/g
%s/<\/strong>//g
%s/<\/td>//g
g/</d
```

Then i stop recording the macros, with

```
q
```

But when I try to play it in another file with

```
@C
```

it does nothing. It just sits there displaying @c in the command line, but nothing else. I tried putting it in my .vimrc file, like this

```
let @c ="
    v/sequence One\|sequence two/d
    %s/sequence three//g
    %s/sequence four/,/g
    %s/ /_/g
    %s/<\/strong>//g
    %s/<\/td>//g
    g/</d
"
```

still nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Vim's macros are rock-solid. How do you open the second file? In a split? In a tab? In another GUI window? Can you record/play any macro at all or only this one?

Comment: @vonHippie, Instead of saying "ignore this question," why not post an answer to your question, or delete the question?

Comment: I wrote an explanation of why it didn't work. Macros don't work if you copy and paste the commands.

Answer (score 0):

A late answer, but I think the problem is that the macro register is `c` and you are/were trying to invoke the macro `C`: the capitalization is different in your posted example.